# How to e-mail a report in Multicat

Tags: report

How can I e-mail a report or document in Multicat BMS?

1. I generated a report and clicked on the Email button on the Report Items menu.

   > The system opens a dialog but what e-mail account is used and how can I track the history or replies?
2. Can I e-mail a document like an Invoice without first saving it as a PDF document?

Answer (score 0):

I will answer the 2 questions separately:

1. I generated a report and clicked on the Email button on the Report Items menu. The system opens a dialog but what e-mail account is used and how can I track the history or replies?

> Multicat BMS has an built-in e-mail client that can be configured under Maintenance->E-mail Accounts.
>
> Each account is also linked to a function like "Customer Statements" with the appropriate account flag.
>
> You cannot currently see general e-mail history but e-mails are visible in modules like job cards under Events tab.
>
> You can view incoming e-mails (replies) on the e-mail maintenance screen but you may also want to set up a mail account on the Outlook for the responsible persons in the company.

2. Can I e-mail a document like an Invoice without first saving it as a PDF document?

> Yes, when you click the Print button on the document, the print preview opens together with the Print Actions menu.  Use the "E-mail" button to send the document from the system using the configured e-mail address as described above.